# 英語が残っている: ユーザー一覧 > 編集者のツールチップ: Users who edited at least 5 posts

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

URL:  
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users  
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users

[image: Users who edited at least 5 posts]

Answer (score 1):

> 投稿を 5 つ以上編集したユーザー

Comment: 翻訳を更新しました（次回のビルドで適用）。